# Get CActiveDataProvider data in the View

Tags: php, yii

How to get `CActiveDataProvider` data directly, without using `CGridView`?

Controller.php

```
public function actionList($id)
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Events', array(
            'criteria' => $criteria
    ));

    $this->render('list',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

View.php:

```
<?php echo $dataProvider->name; ?> // Return Error
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CActiveDataProvider provides data in terms of ActiveRecord **objects** , use `getData()` method to get all activerecord objects that are in the dataprovider

```
$models =$dataProvider->getData()

foreach($models as $model)
{
 echo $model->name;
}
```